# Neutron dipole moment and $\theta -$term

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, instantons

In many references is stated that by having QCD $\theta -$term, 
$$
L_{\theta} = \frac{g_{s}^{2}}{8 \pi^{2}}\theta F \wedge F,
$$ 
we may compute the value of neutron dipole moment,

$$
d \approx |\theta | \frac{em_{\pi}^{2}}{\Lambda_{QCD}^{3}}
$$

How to show that?